# How to randomly sample 50% of items per category in Pandas

Tags: python

I have a Python pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Company Industry.   Review
google    tech      google is an excellent place to work
google    tech      upper management
google    tech      innovative
verizon   comm      good benefits
verizon   comm      open door policy
gucci     fashion   good pay
gucci     fashion   ok place to work
gucci     fashion   slow 
gucci     fashion   inflexible
```

I'd like to random sample half of the reviews per company for training, and have the other half as the test dataset. How do I get a random 50% of the reviews per firm?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```py
df.groupby('Company').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5))
```

[image]